# Finding custom .config file in azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

So I have this simple code to get appsettings from a custom config that works locally:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();

configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "My.config"; // This works locally but not on azure I think
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

AppSettingsSection section = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
var test = section.Settings["test"].Value; // throws nullref
```

Now, I have the "My.config" in another project, and is set to "copy always" to build directory and it works perfectly when debugging using Azure-cli (localhost). In fact, I think that this used to work in Azure before but it doesn't anymore?

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to configure these in the Azure portal using the application settings:

[image: appsettings]

All the settings here will overwirte whatever you had in either your web/app.config or your local.settings.json:

[image: appsettings2]

Comment: But there I can only add appsettings to the regular config file, I'd like to open a custom .config file

Comment: In that case, the only thing I can suggest is to upload your custom config to a storage account and access it from there.  I suppose it does beg the question as to what problem you are trying to solve with a custom config file.

Comment: App Settings in Azure are exposed as env vars, so try to read them as env vars, else fallback to your file.

Comment: @pm_2 Okay, +1 anyway =). Thanks a lot for the solution. To answer: We have a lot of .config files in different backend projects and we are in a transition phase where we are putting the api and backend in azure. Not my call